# PHP - remove all leaves out of multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, data-structures

How to **remove all leaves from a multidimensional array**?

This piece of code gives me **all the leaves**, I am looking for the **opposite** result:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));

foreach($iterator as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = array($key, $value);
}
```

Is there something **built-in**? Or any other **elegant** solution?

Comment: Post your array structure along with expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ParentIterator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.parentiterator.php) can help you.

```
<?php
$array = [
    'a',
    'b'=>[
        'c'=>[],
        'd'
    ],
    'e',
    'f'=>[
        'g'=>[
            'h',
            'i'=>[
                'j'=>[],
                'k'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new ParentIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)
    ),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
);

$result = [];

foreach($rii as $key => $dummy) {
    echo $key, "\r\n";
}
```

prints

```
c
b
j
i
g
f
```

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for except one thing - the result is not in the same order as the original array. How can I output it in the same order?

Comment: That would be SELF_FIRST insteaf of CHILD_FIRST